# How to log messages to Azure Event Hub from Azure API Management Service

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-eventhub

In one of the recent project, I need to add messages(>200kb) to Azure Event Hub through an endpoint exposed by Azure API Management Service. Then, the Stream Analytics job reads this message from Event Hub and writes it to the respective tables in SQL Server.

I was using "log-to-eventhub" policy to log the messages to event hub. But it has a size limitation associated with it, which is 200kb.

What would be the best approach to overcome this size limitation or should I consider a different way to log the payload to Event Hub?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a limit about this described in **[official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-log-event-hubs)**.

> The **maximum** supported message size that can be sent to an event hub
> from this API Management policy is **200 kilobytes (KB)**. If a message
> that is sent to an event hub is larger than 200 KB, it will be
> **automatically truncated**, and the truncated message will be transferred
> to event hubs.

You could consider using [Azure Event Hubs output binding for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-output?tabs=csharp).

About [How Function consume Event Hubs events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reliable-event-processing#how-azure-functions-consumes-event-hubs-events), you could try using multiple parallel Functions instances under consumption plan.

Comment: Thanks @Doris for your response. But I am across the size limitation associated with the "log-to-eventhub" policy. Now I am looking at the approach to use azure function to add the payload to the event hub. But I am wondering whether azure function and event hub can process millions of messages per seconds.

Comment: You could follow the new link I post, that docs described the details about Azure Functions reliable event processing. @sj'

Comment: @DorisLv I don't think this is the valid answer. The issue here is that APIM itself will send truncated logs to EventHub if it's above 200KB. The question is about getting the entire data instead of truncated one.